# "TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: python, iteration, typeerror

I have two matrices

```
fi = [[f1],           Nij = [[N11 N12 .......N1n],
      [f2],                  [N21 N22 .......N2n],
       .                            ...
       .                            ...
      [fn]]                  [Nn1 Nn2 .......Nnn]]
```

I want to multiply:

```
f1 to each element of the 1st row,
f2 to each element of the 2nd row,
```

and so on.

I.e. I want `Xij = fi*Nij` where fi is a column matrix and Xij & Nij is nxn matrix.

I tried using

```
import numpy as np

fi = np.linspace(1,5, num =5)
fi = np.asmatrix(fi)

def Xij(ai):
    Nij = np.ones((5,5))
    for i in range(len(fi)):
    for j in range(len(fi)):
        Xij[i,j] = ai[i] * Nij[i,j]
return Xij

Zij = Xij(fi)
```

It gives me this error `TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment`

Why? and how do I solve this?

Comment: Don't name your functions the same things as variables, it makes things muddy and is the source of your confusion here.

Comment: Got it! the HOW part atleast that too with help.

should not convert fi to a matrix (removing the 2nd line in the code makes it work)

but cant understand why part !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
Xij[i,j] = ai[i] * Nij[i,j]
```

You named a variable `Xij`, but also a function.  Furthermore, when you named the function, it overwrote the variable.

Because of this, when you try to index the function and assign its items, an error is generated because you can't do that on the function.  Below is an example:

```
>>> def test(): print "Hi"
...
>>> test[1] = "yo!"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

Does that error look familiar?  It is the same one you generated because I did exactly what you did.

To fix this problem, change the name of you function to something other than `Xij`.  Doing so will make `Xij` equal the matrice, which will support indexing and item assignment.